# Android RatingBar stars mismatched. Showing different stars when empty and when filled

Tags: android, ratingbar, mismatch

This is a very weird issue I've encountered on a OnePlus 3T only. The RatingBar shows 6 empty stars and when user tries to select the rating on the stars, that shows correctly on top as how it should as per 5 stars. However, because the empty number of stars is different than the filled stars, the overlay looks mismatched. Screenshot attached.

This is the rating bar I have in the XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingProvider"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="5"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:progressTint="@color/rating_filled"
        android:rating="0"
        android:stepSize="0.5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

It works fine in all other devices

[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mms75.png)

Comment: have you tried to use another style?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Which other style for example?

Comment: maybe `style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"` ....it´s just for test how the stars will be shown, even it doesn´t fit to your needs, try it. The rating bar is a little bit buggy, I read many posts that it doesn´t behave like it should.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Alright, this worked style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
But when I change it back to style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle", same problem happens again

Comment: ok, is it important to set the width of the linearLayout where the rating bar is inside wo match_parent? If not, set it to wrap_content. Otherwise it will be shown as your issue not only on OnePlus 3T, there might be other devices with that problem. It seems to me like the rating bar is not really good implemented in android.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Making the LinearLayout width = "wrap_content" also did not work. :(
What I don't understand is that the filled stars work fine, only the background stars get messed up, both of which are essentially part of the same View element. 
Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: I guess the rating bar is poorly implemented and buggy. I have read much posts about not working rating bar. I haven´t tried it, but maybe this works better: https://github.com/kanytu/custom-rating-bar or try this tutorial:http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.de/2013/01/how-to-use-and-custom-ratingbar-in.html

Comment: Hi I have the same problem on Galaxy S9+. I tried on others devices and it works well. Did you find any solution ? Thank you.

Comment: @Pipo We started using this library for rating bar and it works great! https://github.com/techery/ProperRatingBar